# PhantomJS evaluate with basic auth returning null

Tags: javascript, basic-authentication, phantomjs

I am trying to use PhantomJS on a page with basic always auth, for example, this page

http://alexturpin.net/auth (`test:rosebud`)

Using the following code

```
var webpage = require('webpage');

page = webpage.create();
page.settings = {
    userName: "test",
    password: "rosebud"
};

page.open("http://alexturpin.net/auth/", function(status) {
    console.log(status);
    var retval = page.evaluate(function() {
        return "test";
    });
    console.log(retval);
});
```

I get this output

```
$ phantomjs test.js
success
null
```

Whatever I try, `evaluate` will keep returning `null`, even though the page seems to have been opened fine because `status` contains `"success"`.

If I decide to open a page with no basic auth, like http://alexturpin.net/noauth, I still get the same results. Only when I finally remove the authentication settings altogether before opening the page does it work.

The use of authentication settings seem to be conflicting with the `evaluate`. Is this a bug in PhantomJS, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With that syntax you are wiping out the settings object, replacing it with only `userName` and `password`. Use that code to set them:

```
page.settings.userName = "test";
page.settings.password = "rosebud";
```

Probably PhantomJS should handle that better, i.e. not rely on the `settings` object for defaults.

Comment: Oh, don't forget to `phantom.exit();`

Comment: Ah, should have thought of that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -2):

This is a closure issue, try to put your console.log in a callback

Comment: It's not. You don't understand the question.